# Put a dynamic src for an img (React/JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a function that returns a img tag with a dynamic src,

Everything works but I want to make it shorter :

Dirty version

```
import CHALLENGER from "../images/lol/emblems/CHALLENGER.png";
import GRANDMASTER from "../images/lol/emblems/GRABDMASTER.png";
import MASTER from "../images/lol/emblems/MASTER.png";

export const getImageRank = (rank) => {
    if (rank === "CHALLENGER") {
    return (
      <img
        src={CHALLENGER}
        alt="Emblem"
        title={rank}
        style={{ width: "150px" }}
      />
    );
  }

  if (rank === "GRANDMASTER") {
    return (
      <img
        src={GRANDMASTER}
        alt="Emblem"
        title={rank}
        style={{ width: "150px" }}
      />
    );
  }

  if (rank === "MASTER") {
    return (
      <img src={MASTER} alt="Emblem" title={rank} style={{ width: "150px" }} />
    );
  }
};
```

Cleaner attempt version

```
export const getImageRank = (rank) => {
    return (
    <img
      src={require(`../images/lol/emblems/${rank}.png`)}
      alt="Emblem"
      title={rank}
      style={{ width: "150px" }}
    />
  );
};
```

But for my cleaner attempt, the image is not shown :(

Comment: not sure if that's a typo, but is the 'GRANDMASTER' rank supposed to be GRABDMASTER.png?

Comment: Oh thanks that's a typo but from the stackoverflow topic, in the file it's ok, thanks !

Comment: where is the rank coming from?

Comment: it's a function in a separated file, the rank comes from the argument passed to the function when it's executed in another file, and the solution below is working, don't spend time on it it's ok now !

Comment: no problem, happy it was figured out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kind of a solution; you can put the images to an object

```
const images = { CHALLENGER, GRANDMASTER, MASTER };
```

and then

```
<img
    src={images[rank]}
    alt="Emblem"
    title={rank}
    style={{ width: "150px" }}
  />
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it this way. Inside the src it will do some conditional rendering stuff and set the desired value for the src.

```js
import CHALLENGER from "../images/lol/emblems/CHALLENGER.png";
import GRANDMASTER from "../images/lol/emblems/GRABDMASTER.png";
import MASTER from "../images/lol/emblems/MASTER.png";

export const getImageRank = (rank) => {
    return (
    <img

      src={rank === 'CHALLENGER' ? CHALLENGER
      : rank === 'GRANDMASTER' 
      ? GRANDMASTER 
      : MASTER}

      alt="Emblem"
      title={rank}
      style={{ width: "150px" }}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of situation, the best practice is that you need to create a key Value data structure (mostly called HashMap) of your images that holds the required data for each condition. based on that condition that your component faces with ( your `rank` prop that you pass to the component), you will decide to show which image to the user like below:

```
import CHALLENGER from "../images/lol/emblems/CHALLENGER.png";
import GRANDMASTER from "../images/lol/emblems/GRABDMASTER.png";
import MASTER from "../images/lol/emblems/MASTER.png";

const imageOptions = {
  "CHALLENGER": {
    src: CHALLENGER
    style: {{...some style }}
    alt: 'some alt description'
  }
  "GRANDMASTER": {
    src: GRANDMASTER
    style: {{...some style }}
    alt: 'some alt description'
  }
  "MASTER": {
    src: MASTER
    style: {{...some style }}
    alt: 'some alt description'
  }
]

export const getImageRank = (rank) => {
  return (
    <img {...imageOptions[rank]}/>
  )
}
```

So Yes, You still going to need to import all types of images required to show in this component! but react does not allows you to import an image dynamically right from your JSX part of the code.

Also, I have to note that having an Object configuration and selecting from that based on the property that you have acted in O(n) and is good for the performance of your application! because you made just a selection from a configuration object!

Answer (score 1):

```
const ShowImage = ({ image }) => {
  const imageToDisplay = {
    code: CODE,
    master: MASTER,
  };

  return (
    <img
      src={imageToDisplay[image]}
      alt="Emblem"
      title={"rank"}
      style={{ width: "150px" }}
    />
  );
};
```